# Set a Broadcast Receiver for permission used by other app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I have 2 applications. `App1` and `App2`. Suppose the `App1` has a permission tag in its manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

I want to initiate a broadcast receiver in `App2`, whenever `App1` uses this permission i.e. whenever `App1` accesses camera. Note that `App1` does not broadcast this event using `sendBroadcast()` method. Is this possible to set a Broadcast Receiver based on permission used by other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to set a Broadcast Receiver based on permission used by other applications?

No. Apps are not informed, by any means, when another app happens to do something that involves some permission.

Comment: Did not understand your answer entirely. Please explain!